# question about web scraping(as a beginner)

Tags: web-scraping

I have a hobby of reading news. The problem is, there are quite a lot of websites I often go to, and this gives me an idea: building my own database of news. The idea is similar to the newspaper clippings. For example, I read something interesting about Germany economics news, therefore, I can use this software to save all the text and images from the said site(into my computer), and I can add tags such as "Germany", "econ" so I can find it and read it later. I shared this idea with my friend and he said web scraping is not easy because not every site allows you to do that. So my question is, how should I begin this with? I study computer engineering so I got some programming understanding but obviously not enough. Any clues or experience(for the web scraping and tagging) sharing will be helpful, thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty fond of pocket https://getpocket.com/

Answer (score 0):

Python has a couple of good web-scraping tools that work well. `Beautiful Soup 4, Scrapy, Selenium, requests` to name a few.
Before web scraping I would recommend to learn the basics of python and how the web works.

Note that most websites disregard it if you scrape them. It is hard for them to track you doing it and if you only download a few specific sites it shouldnt be something they complain about - as it is not much more than pressing CTRL+C and download the whole site as an HTML.
Don't share it and don't spam requests - be a fair player. If you want to be on the safe side check out TOS of the website.